# Get the value of Json Array in View from Controller Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, each

I need to get the value of the Json Array in the View Page that i have assigned in Rails 4.

My Controller: **profile_controller.rb**

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def initialize
    super
    @search_value=[]
  end

  def search_view
    @user_gender=params[:gender]
    @user_t_table=User.where.not(gender: @user_gender)
    @user_t_table.each do |user|
    sql = "SELECT users.id, users.first_name FROM users LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id LEFT JOIN educations ON users.id = educations.user_id LEFT JOIN usercontacts ON users.id = usercontacts.user_id WHERE  user_profiles.height >='1' AND user_profiles.height <='3' AND user_profiles.marital_status='1' AND user_profiles.mother_tongue='1' AND usercontacts.country_id='1' AND usercontacts.state_id='1' AND usercontacts.city_id='1' AND educations.highest_education='1' AND users.religion_id='1' AND users.caste_id='1' AND users.id ='#{user.id}'"
    records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
    @search_value << records_array
  end
end
```

I need @search_value to be printed in the View page and here is my json Output that i get when i put render to the Value.

**Json Output is:**

```
[[{"id":1,"first_name":"sharma","0":1,"1":"sharma"}],[]]
```

My view Page is **search_view.html.erb**

```
<% @search_value.each_with_index do |group,index| %>
  <!-- Render stuff -->
  <% group.each_with_index do |child,indexs| %>
    <!-- Render child stuff -->
    <%= child  %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I need to get the **id** from the json Output. Pls help to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: [Array#flatten](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten)

```
 > search_result = [[{"id":1,"first_name":"sharma","0":1,"1":"sharma"}],[]]
 > search_result.flatten
 #=> [{:id=>1, :first_name=>"sharma", :"0"=>1, :"1"=>"sharma"}]
```

In your view file **search_view.html.erb**:

```
<% @search_value.flatten.each_with_index do |group,index| %>
  <%= group["id"] %>      
  <%= group["first_name"] %>
<% end %>
```

**Note:** Your `@search_value`'s JSON output is not seems like json. json looks like `"[[{\"id\":1,\"first_name\":\"sharma\",\"0\":1,\"1\":\"sharma\"}],[]]"` anyway you can parse your json using [JSON.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Comment: I am getting the flatten output as what you have mentioned but in view i am not getting any output when i try the code as in the view you suggested.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P: can you provide me output of `group`, just print it using `<%= group %>` or try using `group["id"]` may be you are not getting your key as symbol

Comment: My @search_value is .json format alone. When i put it in json online it is showing the json is correct. As of now when i flatten the value of the '@search_value'  
@search=@search_value.flatten 
render :json=>@search 
The output for this is [{"id":1,"first_name":"sharma","0":1,"1":"sharma"}]

Comment: @NareshKumar.P : provide me value of `@search` what you are getting. I tried and it works for me, [check this Repl Demo](https://repl.it/CTON)

Comment: I am using this code for getting this Output 
'@search = @search_value.flatten
render :json=>@search'
My Output is : [{"id":1,"first_name":"sharma","0":1,"1":"sharma"}]

Comment: I need to print the above output in the search_view.html.erb not in controller

Comment: @NareshKumar.P : check my updated answer, `In your view file search_view.html.erb:`

Comment: Thanks bro. Worked Perfect

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON.parse:

```
JSON.parse(group)["id"]
```

That would be nicer in a view helper method though.

Answer (score 0):

You may change search_view like this:

```
def search_view
  @user_gender=params[:gender]
  @user_t_table=User.where.not(gender: @user_gender)
  @search_value += @user_t_table.flat_map do |user|
    sql = "SELECT users.id, users.first_name FROM users LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id LEFT JOIN educations ON users.id = educations.user_id LEFT JOIN usercontacts ON users.id = usercontacts.user_id WHERE  user_profiles.height >='1' AND user_profiles.height <='3' AND user_profiles.marital_status='1' AND user_profiles.mother_tongue='1' AND usercontacts.country_id='1' AND usercontacts.state_id='1' AND usercontacts.city_id='1' AND educations.highest_education='1' AND users.religion_id='1' AND users.caste_id='1' AND users.id ='#{user.id}'"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

But probably you need this behavior (clean up results between requests):

```
def search_view
  @user_gender=params[:gender]
  @user_t_table=User.where.not(gender: @user_gender)
  @search_value = @user_t_table.flat_map do |user|
    sql = "SELECT users.id, users.first_name FROM users LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id LEFT JOIN educations ON users.id = educations.user_id LEFT JOIN usercontacts ON users.id = usercontacts.user_id WHERE  user_profiles.height >='1' AND user_profiles.height <='3' AND user_profiles.marital_status='1' AND user_profiles.mother_tongue='1' AND usercontacts.country_id='1' AND usercontacts.state_id='1' AND usercontacts.city_id='1' AND educations.highest_education='1' AND users.religion_id='1' AND users.caste_id='1' AND users.id ='#{user.id}'"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

Comment: How i need to print the value in view {"id"=>1, "first_name"=>"sharma", 0=>1, 1=>"sharma"} . I am getting this output when i render the '@search_value' outside the end of flat_map.